# How can I find the highest Int in a Struct in Swift

Tags: swift, struct

Assuming I have a struct such as:

```
struct TestStruct {
    var name: String
    var rank: Int
}

var foo1 = [TestStruct]()
```

What is the most efficient way to find the highest `rank` value inside `foo1` ? Is it somehow possible to use `maxElement()`on a Struct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can make your struct conform to the `Comparable` protocol:

```
struct Test : Comparable {
    let rank: Int
}

func ==(lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
    return lhs.rank == rhs.rank
}

func <(lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
    return lhs.rank < rhs.rank
}

let foo1 = [
    Test(rank: 4),
    Test(rank: 8),
    Test(rank: 2),
    Test(rank: 7)
]
```

Then you can use `foo1.maxElement()` with Swift 2 or `maxElement(foo1)` with Swift 1.2

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it but I get  'ViewController. Test' does not conform to protocol 'Comparable' ... What gives ?

Comment: You need to implement the methods of Comparable in your struct. You can do that in an extension.

Comment: @anto0522 Yes, as he said. Also just look at the code I provided, you have to implement `==` and `<`

Comment: Thank you guys, I have implemented the methods of comparable in my struct but now I get  `[(ViewController. TestStruct)]' does not have a member named 'maxElement'` when I want to get the max value ... any ideas ?

Comment: @anto0522 Maybe you're using Swift 1.2? You have to show some more code, it's really hard to just guess. In case you are using swift 1.2, you can use the global function `maxElement(foo1)`

Comment: I am actually using swift 1.2 that did the trick ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can with Swift 2:

```
let max = foo1.maxElement({ $0.rank < $1.rank })
```

Here's an example with data:

```
struct TestStruct {
    var name = ""
    var rank: Int
    init(rank: Int) {
        self.rank = rank
    }
}

let foo1 = [TestStruct(rank: 2), TestStruct(rank: 5), TestStruct(rank: 12)]

let mx = foo1.maxElement({ $0.rank < $1.rank })

print(mx!) // TestStruct(name: "", rank: 12)
```

*EDIT*

With Swift 1.2 you have to overload the operators like with Kametrixom's answer, then you will write

```
maxElement(foo1)
```

instead of

```
foo1.maxElement()
```

Comment: I tried this and I get an error [(ViewController. TestStruct)]' does not have a member named 'maxElement'... How come ?

Comment: I guess you may not need the _()_ around your block? (If you like)